# Помогите написать цикл, который вызывает метод из инстанса

Tags: java, циклы, while

Всем привет. Решаю задачу. Не могу додуматься. вот есть класс.

```
class Node {
    private int data;
    private Node next;
    
    public Node(int data, Node next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
    
    public Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }
}
```

Допустим есть вот такая строка new Node(1, new Node(2, new Node(3))) из нее должен быть вывод в консоль "1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null".
Таким образом мне необходимо написать цикл, который будет проверять getNext != null и брать getValue следующего инстанса new Node.Не понимаю как мне составить эту цепочку вызовов ведь в методе я не могу создавать объект, чтобы вызвать у него getNext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
Node list = new Node(1, new Node(2, new Node(3)));
Node current = list;

while (current != null) {
  System.out.print(current.getData());
  System.out.print(" -> ");
  current = current.getNext();
}
System.out.println("null");
```

Comment: Спасибо. Идею понял.